# Display title, text content in an xaml in rectangle shape

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display title, text content ( approx 300 characters) from database in an `Updates.xaml` page. The `title, text content` should display in a rectangle blocks. When ever user submit a new update the latest one should automatically display on top of the page and each should be properly spaced between one another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage  
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="soccerapp.UpdatesNews" BackgroundColor="#aa49e3" Title="Updates"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackLayout>
        <!--  Place new controls here  -->
        <Button x:Name="plusButton" 
              Text="+" 
              WidthRequest="60" 
              HeightRequest="60"
              CornerRadius ="30"
              VerticalOptions="Start"
              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
              Clicked="OnPlusButtonClicked" />
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="News!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <ListView x:Name="LstTest" ItemTapped="LstTest_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You stated a number of goals, but what exactly is your problem?

Comment: In the above `xaml`, how can I create a xaml tag to display title and textcontent from database. Single rectangle block where it should display , title and textcontent

Comment: I am kind of confused with xaml,  so don't know how to add tags in above xaml. I have a button in the page, which pop up the title, textcontent fields to get data and submit to database. Later I need to pull data from database to display title and textcontent in above xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ViewCell>
  <Frame>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Content}" />
    </StackLayout>
  </Frame>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Can I ask you one question, If I give `<Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Content}" />` directly inside the `<ViewCell>` the `xaml` is giving following issue.. The property `view` is set more than once.  Why is that so ?

Comment: I have increased the height  of text content as below, but it doesn't increase the height ..`<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="200" View.Margin="20,10,20,10">
        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <Label Text="25-08-2019" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Content}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>`

Comment: "The property view is set more than once" - because View can only contain a single child.  If you have multiple children, you need to wrap then in a container like StackLayout or Grid.